# Who exactly *designed* the test chambers in Portal?

Tags: portal

GLaDOS is certainly the one who *creates* the test chambers, but was she the one who *designed* them in the first place? The [Portal 2 Perpetual Testing Initiative](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7rZO2ACP3A&ab_channel=Valve) video (though just an ad) does seem to indicate that Aperture workers designed at least some of the test chambers. Is there evidence to prove one way or the other, who actually designed the test chambers of either game?

Comment: I don't remember the context, but doesn't GLaDOS at one point indicate a test chamber was designed by "one of Aperture's Nobel Prize recipients", indicating that employees were doing it? Assuming you trust her word, of course.

Answer (score 7):

In Portal 1, it's likely that she simply managed the facility that was designed and built by the Aperture Science team. In Portal 2 however, it can be somewhat believed that she is responsible for the tests.

After Wheatley takes over the facility, he starts using tests that were built by GlaDOS.

> *"This is one of MY tests!"*
>
> *Okay, so the bad news is the tests are MY tests now. So they can kill us."*

[Source](https://theportalwiki.com/wiki/GLaDOS_voice_lines)

The Aperture Science team was merely into testing the capabilities of the Portal mechanisms, rather than putting their test subjects in mortal danger.

In addition to this, the facility has been out of commission, and basically empty for a long time.

> *"Good morning. You have been in suspension for -nine nine nine nine nine... nine ni (continues repeating[...])-"*
>
> *"If the Earth is currently governed by a manner of animal-king, sentient cloud, or other governing body that either refuses to or is incapable of listening to reason, th- [RECORDING SHORTS OUT]"*

[Source](https://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Announcer_voice_lines)

In addition to this, there are several references to GlaDOS having an "itch" that can only be scratched by the completion of tests. Wheatley tests this by routing Chell back through a test chamber that had already been completed, resulting in an unsatisfactory "scratch" response.

So, after putting all this together, I would safely assume that, given her full control of the entire facility, a lack of other personnel, and a need to continue testing, that GlaDOS *did* and *can* design the tests, as well as build them, as it is her primary function - to test.

Answer (score 0):

In the Portal Fandom:

> In Portal 2, these chambers can be swiftly created by GLaDOS with the usage of robotic arms carrying panels and combining them with other panels to form a ceiling, floor, and walls

So it was GLADoS with robotic arms

Comment: OP asks who **designed** those chambers, not who created them. It's already stated that "GLaDOS is certainly the one who creates the test chambers"

Comment: Why not GLADos?

Comment: It could be, but you need proof supporting your statement. As it's written this is just a speculation.